# how to install g77 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

when i type make in my terminal to build libraries and some tests in my machine ,i get this error:

```
g77 -O -fno-automatic -c lsame.f -o lsame.o
make: g77: Command not found
make: *** [lsame.o] Error 127
```

Please help me out.i am unable to install g77 too!

Answer (score 0):

There is GNU Fortran 95 compiler in the repositories, which can be installed by

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

This is the GNU Fortran 95 compiler, which compiles Fortran 95 on platforms supported by the gcc compiler. It uses the gcc backend to generate optimized code. g77 isn't used anymore.